# what is the meaning of $U^{n+1/3}$ ADI method

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-difference-method

For the ADI in numerical method

$$\frac{U^{n+1/3}-U^n}{k/3} = \Delta^2_x U^{n+1/3} + \Delta^2_y U^n + \Delta^2_z U^{n+2/3}$$
$$....$$
$$....$$

don't like $U^{n+1/2} = \dfrac 1 2 (U^{n+1}+U^n),$ I can't find the definition of $U^{n+1/3},U^{n+2/3},$ can some one tell me he definition or it is just a intermedia variables?

Comment: Could it be $U^{n+1/3}=\frac{2}{3}U^{n+1}+\frac{1}{3}U^{n}$ ?

Comment: In general in FD literature, *superscripts* (here $n$) are time indices while *subscripts* (here $x$,$y$,$z$) reflect space variables. In your case, the method hence involves 2 intermediate *time steps* from $$n \to n+1/3 \to n+2/3 \to n+1$$

At each intermediate time step you will be "alternating directions": instead of directly differentiating  $U$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$, you'll first differentiate wrt to $x$ keeping other variables constant ($n \to n+1/3$), then $y$, then $z$  ($n+2/3 \to n+1$)). See the wikipage for an example in 2 dimensions, with half time step $n+1/2$.

Comment: @ Quantuple so, here $U^{n+1/3}$ is an unknown intermedia variable which should be solved from equation system with additional dimensions(can't directly obtained from $U^{n+1}$ and $U^n$)

Comment: @A.Oreo Yes you first solve the implicit representation of the discretised PDE for $U^{n+1/3}$ knowing $U^n$. Then, knowing $U^{n+1/3}$ you look for $U^{n+2/3}$ again solving a linear system. Finally, you'll be able to solve find $U^{n+1}$ using $U^{n+2/3}$ (which will be a non-linear function of $U^n, U^{n+1/2}$)